# Reference for existence of strong solution for semilinear parabolic PDE on unbounded domain with monotone source

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am considering the existence of solutions for the following semilinear parabolic PDE
\begin{cases}
u_t+Lu=f(t,x,u,u_x), &(t,x)\in [0,T]\times\mathbb{R},\\
u(0,x)=g(x),
\end{cases}
where $L$ is a 2nd-order (uniformly) elliptic operator.

I am interested in the existence of classic solution $u\in C^{1,2}([0,T]\times \mathbb{R})$ where $f$ is monotone in $u$ with polynomial growth. Other assumptions can also be imposed.

Is there any reference about this topic for an unbounded domain?